# Is there documentation to write a program to connect to and capture images from a TightVNC server?

Tags: java, vnc, screen-capture

This would be to allow the captured images to be recorded.

TightVNC is similar (perhaps identical in format) to RealVNC. All that is necessary is image capturing and I can write the recording part.

The only helpful language for this situation that I know would be Java.

Answer (score 0):

TightVnc is similar to a remote desktop,

so I suggest using C# and integrate the Expression Encoder 4 sdk.

All the screen capture/recording is done for you, you can even publish if needed to.

Comment: I would be at loss on how to do that unless there was an already written example. If I can get screen shots into Java via direct connection, reading saved files or other means then I am good to go. If there was an already written device that worked,, then I might be able to make use of it without caring the language.

Comment: @George Bailey, The SDK comes with examples. And sorry for Java, I do not use it for such deeds, especially since I think it be hard for it to grab a buffer from the windows.

Comment: I am not grabbing a buffer from the windows. I am grabbing it from a VNC connection over the internet or any other connection to a local Viewer. The remote PC is the one that actually grabs the screenshots and sends them to VNC clients.

Comment: @George Bailey, Do not know how to access data from the vnc. you should probably look in with them ... Otherwise, making an application on the desktop of the remote computer and making that application do the job for u and send you whatever data you need sounds more plausible at my current knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for the Java version of the RealVNC client is available for download at http://www.realvnc.com/products/download.html

I would think that would be the best place to start.